# formsauthentication.setauthcookie default expiration?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I thought it was years, but it is getting cleared within 1 hour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx), "The default value is 30 minutes":

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="30"
           ...
```